# Android Inside Adapter view redraw not working?

Tags: android, view, gallery, adapter, android-linearlayout

I'm doing galleryview using Adapter.

In that adapter i'm using linear layout. In that linear layout textview i'm adding dynamically.

```
class ViewHolder{
        TextView txt_title;     
        LinearLayout linear_insideLay;
    }

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();

        try{
        vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.homepagelist_1_adapter,null);
        holder.txt_title=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txt_title); 
        holder.linear_insideLay=LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.linear_insideLay);
vi.settag(holder);
}catch{}
}
```

Here i'm adding dyanamically.

```
private void updateDetails(
    int linksize=singleVenueList.getLinkskeyList().size();
                try{
                    myHolder.add_link1.removeAllViews();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

    for(int i=0;i<linksize;i++){
                    TextView addText=new TextView(activity);        
                    addText.setText(singleVenueList.getLinkskeyList().get(i));
                    addText.setTextSize(22);
                    addText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    addText.setTag(singleVenueList.getLinksvalueList().get(i));
                    addText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
                    myHolder.linear_insideLay.addView(addText,lp);

                    addText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String url=v.getTag().toString();
                            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(activity,WebView_Link.class);
                            bundle.putString("URL", url);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
                        }
                    });


        }
}
```

In this Gallery every item i'm called updateDetails() method remove working fine. aging i'm trying to add new list in that linearlLayout not added.display empty data.

note:
if i'm without remove view added previousList + currentList added.
tried invalidate(); and this.notifyDataSetChanged(); that also not working.

please suggest correct way.

thanks.